# Access title inside id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am having trouble to access title inside an ID object.
I want to access item.title. But i am not able to give a name to the object ID.
I tried doing `order.cart.items.item.title`

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d60d1752cda6403e4f868af"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-08-24T05:55:34.741Z"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5d60d00e4c865312ccf3f18a"),
    "cart" : {
        "items" : {
            "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96" : {
                "item" : {
                    "_id" : "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96",
                    "imagePath" : "https://dks.scene7.com/is/image/GolfGalaxy/18NIKWRMX270XXXXXLFS_Black_Cream?wid=1080&fmt=jpg",
                    "title" : "Nike ",
                    "description" : "Nike Airmax",
                    "price" : 10,
                    "category" : "shoes",
                    "__v" : 0
                },
                "qty" : 1,
                "price" : 10
            }
        },
        "totalQty" : 1,
        "totalPrice" : 10
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Object.values` for that, because of the ID. This allows you to get the object with the key of `5d60cddb69f460191c680e96` without the key:

```
Object.values(order.cart.items)[0].item.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =  {
    "cart" : {
        "items" : {
            "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96" : {
                "item" : {
                    "_id" : "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96",
                    "imagePath" : "https://dks.scene7.com/is/image/GolfGalaxy/18NIKWRMX270XXXXXLFS_Black_Cream?wid=1080&fmt=jpg",
                    "title" : "Nike ",
                    "description" : "Nike Airmax",
                    "price" : 10,
                    "category" : "shoes",
                    "__v" : 0
                },
                "qty" : 1,
                "price" : 10
            }
        },
        "totalQty" : 1,
        "totalPrice" : 10
    }};
for (let id in data.cart.items)
  console.log(data.cart.items[id].item.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by getting `key name` of an `object` using `Object.keys()` methods, This methods returns an array of `key names`

```
const obj = { id: 1 };
const keysArray = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keysArray);.  // ["id"]
```

In your case only one keys are present in the object, So we can directly get that name with index 0 (`Object.keys(obj)[0]`)

Check below snippet

```js
const cart ={
"items": {
    "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96": {
        "item": {
            "_id": 
        "5d60cddb69f460191c680e96",
            "imagePath": '',
            "title": "Nike ",
            "description": "Nike",
            "price": 10,
            "category": "shoes",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 10
     }
 }
};
 
    const id = 
 Object.keys(cart.items)[0];
  
 console.log(
  cart.items[id].item.title
  );
```